# Почему не работает цикл для прохода по кнопкам и удаления их класса?

Tags: javascript

Основная задумка в том, чтобы при нажатии на какую-то кнопку кнопка нажатая до этого 'потухала'. Но почему-то в итоге я просто кликаю по кнопкам и они поочередно активируются, при этом другие также активны. Я не могу понять, что в коде не так.

JS:

```
function colorChanger(obj){ 
            let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
            for (let i; i < elem.length; i++) {
                if (elem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
                    elem[i].remove('active')
                }
            }
            obj.classList.add('active')
        }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="colorChanger(this)" class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger(this)" class="btn">Button 2</button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger(this)" class="btn">Button 3</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: В obj что лежит? Html покажите. А вообще такие штуки надо учится делать самому - навешайте console.log или через debugger в chrome тормозите код, смотрите что у вас в переменных на каждом шаге. Где-то что-то не находит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в цикле, я не задал начальное значение i...

```
for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {...
```

А так, все работает как и задумано

Answer (score 0):

Пропробуйте так

```
function colorChanger(obj){ 
            let elem = [...document.getElementsByClassName('btn')]
            for (let i; i < elem.length; i++) {
                if (elem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
                    elem[i].remove('active')
                }
            }
            obj.classList.add('active')
        }
```